# C++ Exception to Exception-less

Tags: c++, google-chrome, exception, webassembly, emscripten

I am looking to compile some C++ code that makes heavy usage of exceptions into a wasm target. Unfortunately, most browsers don't have Webassembly Exception Handling turned on (I believe only Chrome supports it behind the flag `chrome://flags#enable-webassembly`), and there's a tremendous performance hit in how emscripten wraps exceptions into a javascript `try/catch`. We've noticed about a 2x performance hit when the flag is turned on or off.

I believe the short-answer to this is 'no', but I was wondering if there are known approaches to translate C++ code-with-exceptions to C++ code that doesn't use exceptions at all (not even in a parent wrapper) without manually translating it.

Comment: Does "without manually translating it" mean _without editing the code_?  Are you asking how to make code faster without changing it?

Comment: @DrewDormann no I meant more if there was a transpiler or something rather than just 'rewriting the code from scratch to not use exceptions'.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that Exceptions have in common with Return values is that it's a form of error handling, code-wise, they are entirely two different things.

Barring any existing infrastructure where you can disable exceptions such as `#define BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS` in Boost, and disabling exception support with a compiler flag like `-fno-exceptions` *(which will also make std near impossibe to use)*.. The only way is to manually edit... However, it is possible to return an error object, or throw it, which can make it easier to gradually introduce return values.

Answer (score 1):

**UseNoexceptFalse:**

Use **UseNoexceptFalse** option to false.
Enabled by default, When you disable it, it will replace **throw** with **noexcept**

**Example:**

```
void foo() throw(int) {}

struct bar {
  void foobar() throw(int);
  void operator delete(void *ptr) throw(int);
  void operator delete[](void *ptr) throw(int);
  ~bar() throw(int);
}
```

**Transformed Example:**

```
void foo() {}

struct bar {
  void foobar();
  void operator delete(void *ptr) noexcept(false);
  void operator delete[](void *ptr) noexcept(false);
  ~bar() noexcept(false);
}
```

For further clarification:
[modernize-use-noexcept](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/modernize-use-noexcept.html)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the exceptions in the browsers will be optimized with time. I also think that the exceptions MUST ([RFC 2119](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2119)) not be used for a base of a computation, but only for events that SHOULD NOT ([RFC 2119](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2119)) happen.

Clearly "should" is relative and varies from person to person (project to project), but a disk error is clearly an event that should not happen (except, in the case when your program works with broken disks, and a disk error is a normal event). When the performance is an issue, changing the code seems to be the best solution.

An automatic translation sounds better, but when I think how often the standards are changing 11, 17, 20... I do not think that such a translation system will be managing to keep up, because its use cases would not be that much (personal opinion), that it might not worth developing it in the first place.

Anyway, a quick solution would be to wrap each exported function in a new catch-friendly one, that catches the exceptions and turns them into return values (or stores this information into thread-local variables), distinguishable from the normal return value, if any. That way at least the exceptions would not propagate to the JS side.

Comment: cool, could you link to the RFC's as well so easier to reference?

Comment: Done. That RFC is from my favorite ones.

Comment: got it, and any notes on why (or when) you think the browser exceptions will be optimized? Now it currently gives a 2x performance hit.

Comment: "Why" is easy. Because the the exceptions are relatively new, and are not yet standardized: https://webassembly.org/roadmap/ and https://github.com/WebAssembly/proposals. "When" is a hard one. Firefox supports WebAssembly sins v52 (https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/52.0/releasenotes/), and the calls between it and JS became fast somewhere around year and half later (https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/10/calls-between-javascript-and-webassembly-are-finally-fast-%F0%9F%8E%89/). So I guess that after a year and half, that makes it 2023, if the trend continues. But its impossible to know for sure.

Comment: There is no information provided by OP showing the heavy overhead on the exception handling _is_ the result of abuse as "a base of a computation". And you have misused the verbs from RFC 2119 in a typical way. These verbs should be used to mandate or suggest requirements in some normative rules of specifications. You should show the concrete references in the related specification to convince the readers that your statements are true, not just following the suggesting "I think". However, AFAIK, there are no such rules on the normative specifications of languages and the implementations.

Comment: BTW, when using such verbs is a must, I prefer [isodir2](https://www.iso.org/sites/directives/current/part2/index.xhtml) rules instead, which have clearer alternatives without the necessity of the amendment of [RFC 8174](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8174). Also note ISO C++ follows isodir2.

Comment: The words from the specification are properly placed to emphasize my personal opinion (that may or may not be correct), and by this they are reused (and properly cited), not misused. I must not nor should do any of the proposed, but may. The capitalization was edited by another user, I do not mind it to stay. Thank you for the links.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your code you can change *every* function to return `std::variant<OkResult, ERROR>` if it ever throw exception, but using almost every third-party library (including STL) would be impossible or painful.